# How to convert double-quote to single quote of key-values in an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

To generate a .js file, I'm trying to convert a string like that :

```js
let file = "module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet",
    {
      "resolve": "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      "options": {
        "name": "images",
        "path": "${__dirname}/src/images",
      },
    },
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp",
  ],
}
"
```

To that :

```js
let expectedFile = "module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet",
    {
      "resolve": "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      "options": {
        "name": "images",
        "path": `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp",
  ],
}
"
```

I want to do that in order to use my variable `${__dirname}` inside my string. I tried many thing like `` .replace(/"/g, '`') `` but it breaks the created .js file.
Otherwise, the value of each key should be converted like that :

```js
{
 "name": `images`,
 "path": `${__dirname}`,
}
```

Comment: Is the `path` property the only one which will have the `${someExpression}` template literal syntax to be transformed?

Comment: No many properties could be dynamic

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an [XY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) problem with not very many trivial solutions. So here's the thing, javascript is a non regular language you simply cant use regex to do what want since  context is required. You'd need a parser. I think what you are trying to do is simply interpolate values and template literals are just a means to that end.

### Just Use Simple Replacements

Use regex to replace simple interpolation values from a known context.

```js
const INTERPOLATION_MATCH = /\$\{\s*(\w+)\s*\}/g;
const interpolate = (string, values) => {
  return string.replace(INTERPOLATION_MATCH, (_, name) => {
    let result = "";
    const value = values[name];

    if (value != null) {
      result = value;
    }

    return result;
  });
};

// this is done simply to allow multiline data without template literals.
const file = JSON.stringify({
  plugins: [
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet",
    {
      "resolve": "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      "options": {
        "name": "images",
        "path": "${__dirname}/src/images",
      },
    },
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp",
  ]
}, null, 2);

console.log(interpolate(file, { __dirname: "foo" }));
```

`${foo}` is used to match interpolated values, but I would recommend that you instead use something like `{{foo}}` so that its not implied that this will behave the same way as template literals(evaluate an expression), but instead is just a value replacement.

So how do you resolve `__dirname`? Well you know were you are importing the configs from, you can manually resolve them via `path.dirname(require.resolve('your_config_file'))`.

### JSON Revivers

If all you are doing is loading JSON files and interpolating certain values, you could leave the files as JSON and use `JSON.parse` with the `reviver` parameter. This way you don't have to `eval` anything or do anything super fancy.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const readJSON = (file) => {
  const data = fs.readFileSync(file);
  const context = {
    __filename: path.resolve(file),
    __dirname: path.dirname(path.resolve(file)),
  };

  return JSON.parse(data, (_key, value) => {
    let result = value;

    if (typeof value === "string") {
      result = interpolate(value, context);
    }

    return result;
  });
};
```

You might want to replace `path.resolve` with `require.resolve` if you are using configurations from npm packages that should resolve using the normal node resolution strategies.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I need the ```${__dirname}``` to stay like that "path": `${__dirname}` . Not like that : ```"path": "foo"```